# Flyway migration fails even though script runs ok in DB client (MySQL)

Tags: java, mysql, flyway

I'm working on a flyway migration that will write the contents of one table as JSON string in a field of another table. I'm trying to get rid of about 50 of these tables and replace them with fields containing JSON strings.

The problem I'm having is that the query runs fine when I run it in MySQL Workbench, but it fails when I run the flyway migration. I've tried modifying the query. Running a very simple stored procedure works. Running a select on INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS also works ok. I've tried writing the query using SET @qry := () and it makes no difference. I'd appreciate any idea about how to solve this.

```
MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near 'PREPARE stmt FROM @qry;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
--    =========' at line 13
```

This is the query

```
SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len = (10*1024);
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet = (50*1024*1024);
SET @schema = 'db';

SET @table = 'InterfaceTable';
SET @className = 'TestInterfaceConfing';
SET @interfaceType = 'Test';

SELECT CONCAT(
  'UPDATE TestTable as tt SET interfaceConfig=(SELECT CONCAT(TRIM(TRAILING ', QUOTE(','),
  ' FROM CONCAT(', QUOTE('{"@class":"'), ',', QUOTE(@className), ',', QUOTE('",'), ',',
  GROUP_CONCAT(QUOTE('"'), ',', QUOTE(COLUMN_NAME), ',', QUOTE('"'), ',', QUOTE(':'), ',',
  IF(type like '%CHAR', '\'"\',', ''), 'IF(', COLUMN_NAME, ' is null,', IF(type like '%CHAR', '\'\'', QUOTE('null')) , ',', COLUMN_NAME, ')', IF(type like '%CHAR', ',\'"\'', ''), ',', QUOTE(',')),
  ')), ''}'') FROM ', @table, ' as interface WHERE tt.id=interface.id) where tt.interfaceType=', QUOTE(@interfaceType), ';'
)
INTO @qry
FROM
  (SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE as type FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @schema AND TABLE_NAME = @table) t;

PREPARE stmt FROM @qry;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Seems like `MySQLSyntaxErrorException` comes out of the MySQL driver, so worth eliminating Flyway from the equation. You could try creating a [JavaMigration](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migration/java) which supplies you a connection to the database and run the query to determine if the driver is even capable of running that query verbatim.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly due to our parser tripping over the many combinations of quotes. Please file an issue in the issue tracker and include the simplest form of the query that breaks.

Answer (score 0):

I use `com.googlecode.flyway:flyway-core version:2.1.1`

I had to split my 1 long script into parts of 13 scripts.